# How to use docker compose with dokku?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dokku

I'm trying to run matomo in a dokku instance with https://github.com/rclement/dokku-matomo

This dokku setup is using a docker image: https://github.com/crazy-max/docker-matomo

The above dokku setup uses quite an old version of the docker-matomo image (3.5.1). I attempted to update the Dockerfile to pull `crazymax/matomo:latest` (3.13.4-RC1), which seemed to work but now my Dokku container returns an nginx 404.

From what I understand from this issue: https://github.com/crazy-max/docker-matomo/issues/14 there needs to be an update to the configuration of the `traefik.frontend.rule=Host:matomo.example.com` variable in `docker-compose.yml` to point to my Dokku hostname.

I've tried editing and placing the `docker-compose.yml` file in the root of my Dokku repository, but it seems to have no effect. My confusion lies in how to use `docker-compose` with Dokku?

Comment: It's very easy to install Matomo on Dokku. Keep in mind,  all Dokku apps are just Docker containers built when pushed. So you can take a Docker image, re-tag it (as ion the docs) and run it. In the case of Matomo, you'll need mysql. Well just install the Dokku MySQL plugin and `--link` them. With large compose files, perhaps there should be a tool.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do not need to use `docker-compose.yml` to deploy to Dokku. Here is a run through on how to set up [`docker-matomo`](https://github.com/crazy-max/docker-matomo) on Dokku by pulling the image directly from Docker Hub. You should be able to re-use your old database, by using this different deploy method.

```
# Pull image and tag it
docker pull crazymax/matomo:latest
docker tag crazymax/matomo:latest dokku/matomo:v3.13.5

# Create app
dokku apps:create matomo
dokku config:set --no-restart matomo TZ=Europe/Berlin MEMORY_LIMIT=256M UPLOAD_MAX_SIZE=16M OPCACHE_MEM_SIZE=128 REAL_IP_FROM=0.0.0.0/32 REAL_IP_HEADER=X-Forwarded-For LOG_LEVEL=WARN

# Set domain
dokku domains:set matomo matomo.example.com

# Create database
dokku mariadb:create matomo-mariadb

# Create and mount persistent volume
mkdir /var/lib/dokku/data/storage/matomoo
# UID:GUID are set to 101 in the nginx image that crazymax/matomo uses
chown 101:101 /var/lib/dokku/data/storage/matomo
dokku storage:mount matomo /var/lib/dokku/data/storage/matomo:/data

# Add correct proxy ports
dokku proxy:ports-add matomo http:80:8000
dokku proxy:ports-remove matomo http:80:5000

# Deploy app for the first time
dokku tags:deploy matomo v3.13.5

# Setup Let's Encrypt
dokku config:set --no-restart matomo DOKKU_LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=letsencrypt@example.com
dokku letsencrypt matomo
dokku letsencrypt:auto-renew matomo

# Grep MariaDB information for the setup
dokku mariadb:info mariadb-matomo
```

I also created a pull request to update [rclement/dokku-matomo](https://github.com/rclement/dokku-matomo): https://github.com/rclement/dokku-matomo/pull/2

Comment: I will have a look at the PR/update as soon as I have a chance, thank you so much for the explanation and the PR!

Comment: The PR is already merged, so you just need to checkout the `master` branch in the repository!